# D3 orient for multiple axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to display the y axis ticks on the right side of the line, but I want the axis to be oriented on the left hand side.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
var usageAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(usageScale)
                .tickSize(-(width - chartPadding.left + 22))
                .orient('left').ticks(4);
```

I tried to transform the text and line, but not able to reach out.

I want My Axis should look like the below Image :

[image]
Please guide me.

Comment: D3 doesn't support this directly. You could have an axis oriented to the right with no end ticks and add the lines at the end manually.

Comment: How manually I can do that.. If any links or implementation that would be helpful.

Comment: You just need to add `line` elements at the extreme points.